# Recursive maven dependencies with test scope

Tags: java, maven, junit

I have a base project (common) and several projects (P1, P2, ...) dependent on common. All projects have some common dependencies such as JUnit. To avoid replicating the common dependencies, I put them in the common pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

P1 POM depends on common

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I add a JUnit test case to P1, eclipse shows "The import org.junit cannot be resolved". However, when I remove the "test" scope in common pom.xml for junit, the error is resolved.

Why doesn't maven handle the recursive dependencies correctly? What am I missing? Is there a better way to handle the common dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`test` scoped dependencies are never tranistive.

What you can do is split your `common-dependencies` into `common-dependencies` and `common-test-dependencies`.

Both contain all their dependencies in the `compile` (default) scope.

Now you include both dependency-helpers, but the test-dependencies themselves in test scope.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-test-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>test</test>
</dependency>
```

A `compile->test` dependency chain resolves to a `test` dependency for the tranisitive dependency, so you are good to go.

The same technique can be used for the other scopes as well, if needed.

Two points of style:

- if common includes own code as well, consider splitting it into the dependencies part and the common code part
- If you use dependency-only pom projects, call them always `*-dependencies`, so they are easier to understand without looking into them

Answer (score 0):

You can also use different approach using dependencyManagement:

(blackbuild's answer is certainly true, but not the only way to approach it and some people, like me, don't like to create separate module just to manage dependencies).

In root pom you define:

```
<dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
   ...
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and in all sub-modules you refer to this dependency (version and scope are taken from parent pom.xml):

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

Comment: Which is certainly the best and most straight forward approach. However, he explicitly wanted to group them together.